# Get characters to the right of a numerical character in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I was wondering there is a way in Excel to get the characters from each cell right from the number.
For instance the example below

```
PW22CL -> CL
PW22CLB -> CLB
PW22EBS ->EBS
PW22EK -> EK
PW22FL ->FL
PW22HF -> HF
W21M -> M
W21OB ->OB
```

Is there any way I can put regex in the regular LEFT, RIGHT,MID, FIND functions in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use VBA:

**Method 1:** Use this [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))))))
```

**Remember to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.**

---

**Method 2:** Or use this [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),0)))
```

**Remember to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.**

---

**Method 3:** Or this **regular formula** if you are using *Excel 2010 or higher (since it uses the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df))*:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),1))
```

Assumption: Cell `A1` contains the value you need to get the last 2 characters from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this normally entered formula, which should work in most any version of excel.

```
=MID(A2,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))))+1,99)For a non-volatile form, useful if you have a large worksheet,
```

Or, to avoid volatile functions, you can define a Name `seq` where:

```
seq Refers To:  =ROW(INDEX($1:$65536,1,1):INDEX($1:$65536,255,1))
```

Then use this formula:

```
=MID(A1,LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,seq,1)),seq)+1,99)
```

Explanation

- `seq` or `Row(Indirect...` return an array of integers `1..n`
- The second `MID(...` then returns an array of each individual character in the string
- `1/isnumber(-MID(...` then returns an array of either an error or a 1
- The `LOOKUP`, in this situation, will return the position of the last numeric value in the string.  It is matching the last value in the array that is less than lookup_value.  This gives us the starting number of the terminal alpha characters.

Answer (score 0):

How about this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function JunkOnTheRight(sIN As String) As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = Len(sIN) To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Mid(sIN, i, 1)) Then
            JunkOnTheRight = Mid(sIN, i + 1)
        Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]